# function argument type differs without any compilation or runtime error

Tags: go

How come the following code is running? "measure" expects an argument of type geometry, but this code passes argument of "square" type.

```
package main
import "fmt"

type geometry interface {
    area() int
}

type square struct {
    radius int
}
func (s square) area() int {
    return s.radius*s.radius
}

func measure(g geometry) {
    fmt.Println(g)
    fmt.Println(g.area())
}

func main() {
    measure(square{radius: 3})
}
```

The outpust is:

```
{3}
9
```

Thanks

Comment: It's an interface. Please [take the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`square` implements the `geometry` interface because it has the method `area()`. This is exactly the point of interfaces. See: https://tour.golang.org/methods/9